# Normalize skewed distribution

Tags: normalization, normality-assumption, quantiles, skewness

My data is right-skewed.

[image]

Log-transform data only shifts it, not changing the distribution shape.

[image]

Tried to use [QuantileTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.QuantileTransformer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.QuantileTransformer) but output seems to be really messy.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to normalize this distribution?

The purpose of this normalization step is to fit a regression neural network

Comment: For what purpose?  (This is a FAQ but the answer depends on what role the data will play in your analysis.)

Comment: Fitting a regression neural network

Comment: What role?  Response or explanatory variable?  What are you referring to in your supposition that the distribution needs to be "normalized" in this way?

Comment: Skewed distribution tend to bias the model towards the over concentrated region. Gaussianization reduces this effect.

Comment: Why is it bad to bias the model towards the region with the most observations? $\text{//}$ We don't care about normal marginal (pooled) distributions of the response variable (or the predictors) in a linear or logistic regression. Why should it be important in a neural network?